# Why "it is recommended to include foreign key property in the entity class"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

the code from the sample:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public int StdandardRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardRefId")]
    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        StudentsList = new List<Student>();
    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine an scenario where you want to set the relationship but you don't have the `Standard` instance in memory, the only you have is the `StandardId`. This would require you to first execute a query on the database to retrieve that `Standard` instance you need, so that you can set the `Standard` navigation property. There are times when you may not have the object in memory, but you do have access to that object’s key value. With a foreign key property, you can simply use the key value without depending on having that instance in memory:

```
 int standardId=2;
 //...
 student.StdandardRefId =standardId;
```

In summary, whit the FK property you'll have two options to set the relationship.

My recommendation is when you need to create a new `Student` related to an existing `Standard`, set the FK property and not the navigation property. There are scenarios where Entity Framework will set the `Standard`’s state to `Added` even though it already exists in the database, which can cause duplicates in the database. If you are only working with the foreign key, you can avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the virtual Standard Standard property, you have told Entity Framework that your Student object is related to zero or one Standard objects.

In order for Entity Framework to automatically retrieve this object using Lazy Loading (Since you specified virtual), you must also tell it exactly how the objects relate by giving it a foreign key annotation. Entity Framework will automatically attempt to find a matching Standard object in the context whose primary key matches your foreign key when you try to access the Standard property for the first time.

If you do not specify a relationship, you can manually retrieve the Standard object and use the set accessor of your property.